# In The Wolverine, was Logan dreaming or was it real?

Tags: x-men-cinematic-universe, wolverine, marvel, the-wolverine

Keeping the title a bit vague as not to spoil the movie.

In The Wolverine, was Logan dreaming or hallucinating,

> when he was with Jean Gray/Phoenix?

Or was

> Jean Gray/Phoenix some sort of a ghost that was interacting with Logan?

Answer (score 10):

This is left ambiguous in the movie.  It could relate to the Phoenix storyline where she appears briefly at different times until she is reborn.

Comment: That would possibly explain the extra scene at the end of the movie (after the initial credits, presumably leading to X-Men 4).

Answer (score 2):

Repeated references to nightmares in the film, Logan was dreaming of his love for Jean.

Answer (score 1):

Logan was definitely just hallucinating every time he saw Jean after he was forced to kill her. Hope this helps!

Comment: Definitely? Why?

Comment: @MahmudMourad: Reference?

Answer (score 1):

i believe she was really there in his head, talking to him before she was reborn, from what i found out about jean grey as the phoenix, is that when she is killed she has said the she is in some kind of white room before being resurrected, and i believe that's what it was at the end of movie the last time we see her talking to wolverine. so that makes me think she is really there with him.